# when using a void in other class, get error on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-volley

When I'm trying to use other RFID SDK to get Tag Code. And send to the server to fetch the tag information. But I only can get the RFID SDK demon working. So I just try to add HTTP request method into the demon. but I always get an error about I'm calling a null object reference. when I use

```
IAcitivity.IMakeHttpCall();
```

**Inventory Activity**

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.ModelBase;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.TSLBluetoothDeviceActivity;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.WeakHandler;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.AsciiCommander;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.DeviceProperties;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.commands.FactoryDefaultsCommand;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.enumerations.QuerySession;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.enumerations.TriState;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.parameters.AntennaParameters;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.responders.LoggerResponder;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class InventoryActivity extends TSLBluetoothDeviceActivity {
    // Debug control
    private static final boolean D = BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    private RequestQueue mVolleyQueue;
//    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    // The list of results from actions
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mResultsArrayAdapter;
    private ListView mResultsListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mBarcodeResultsArrayAdapter;
    private ListView mBarcodeResultsListView;

    // The text view to display the RF Output Power used in RFID commands
    private TextView mPowerLevelTextView;
    // The seek bar used to adjust the RF Output Power for RFID commands
    private SeekBar mPowerSeekBar;
    // The current setting of the power level
    private int mPowerLevel = AntennaParameters.MaximumCarrierPower;

    // Error report
    private TextView mResultTextView;

    // Custom adapter for the session values to display the description rather than the toString() value
    public class SessionArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QuerySession> {
        private final QuerySession[] mValues;

        public SessionArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, QuerySession[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            mValues = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView view = (TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setText(mValues[position].getDescription());
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView view = (TextView)super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setText(mValues[position].getDescription());
            return view;
        }
    }

    // The session
    private QuerySession[] mSessions = new QuerySession[] {
            QuerySession.SESSION_0,
            QuerySession.SESSION_1,
            QuerySession.SESSION_2,
            QuerySession.SESSION_3
    };
    // The list of sessions that can be selected
    private SessionArrayAdapter mSessionArrayAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);
        mVolleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mResultsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.result_item);
        mBarcodeResultsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.result_item);

        mResultTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

        // Find and set up the results ListView
        mResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resultListView);
        mResultsListView.setAdapter(mResultsArrayAdapter);
        mResultsListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        mBarcodeResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.barcodeListView);
        mBarcodeResultsListView.setAdapter(mBarcodeResultsArrayAdapter);
        mBarcodeResultsListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        // Hook up the button actions
        Button sButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.扫描开始);
        sButton.setOnClickListener(mScanButtonListener);
        Button cButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.清除按钮);
        cButton.setOnClickListener(mClearButtonListener);

        // The SeekBar provides an integer value for the antenna power
        mPowerLevelTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.powerTextView);
        mPowerSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.powerSeekBar);
        mPowerSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mPowerSeekBarListener);

        // Set the seek bar current value to maximum and to cover the range of the power settings
        setPowerBarLimits();

        mSessionArrayAdapter = new SessionArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mSessions);
        // Find and set up the sessions spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sessionSpinner);
        mSessionArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(mSessionArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mActionSelectedListener);
        spinner.setSelection(0);

        // Set up Fast Id check box listener
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.fastIdCheckBox);
        cb.setOnClickListener(mFastIdCheckBoxListener);

        //
        // An AsciiCommander has been created by the base class
        //
        AsciiCommander commander = getCommander();

        // Add the LoggerResponder - this simply echoes all lines received from the reader to the log
        // and passes the line onto the next responder
        // This is added first so that no other responder can consume received lines before they are logged.
        commander.addResponder(new LoggerResponder());

        // Add a synchronous responder to handle synchronous commands
        commander.addSynchronousResponder();

        //Create a (custom) model and configure its commander and handler
        mModel = new InventoryModel();
        mModel.setCommander(getCommander());
        mModel.setHandler(mGenericModelHandler);
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mModel.setEnabled(false);

        // Unregister to receive notifications from the AsciiCommander
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mCommanderMessageReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mModel.setEnabled(true);

        // Register to receive notifications from the AsciiCommander
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mCommanderMessageReceiver,
                  new IntentFilter(AsciiCommander.STATE_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION));

        displayReaderState();
        UpdateUI();
    }


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Menu
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private MenuItem mReconnectMenuItem;
    private MenuItem mConnectMenuItem;
    private MenuItem mDisconnectMenuItem;
    private MenuItem mResetMenuItem;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reader_menu, menu);

        mResetMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.reset_reader_menu_item);
        mReconnectMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.reconnect_reader_menu_item);
        mConnectMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.insecure_connect_reader_menu_item);
        mDisconnectMenuItem= menu.findItem(R.id.disconnect_reader_menu_item);
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Prepare the menu options
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        boolean isConnecting = getCommander().getConnectionState() == AsciiCommander.ConnectionState.CONNECTING;
        boolean isConnected = getCommander().isConnected();
        mResetMenuItem.setEnabled(isConnected);
        mDisconnectMenuItem.setEnabled(isConnected);

        mReconnectMenuItem.setEnabled(!(isConnecting || isConnected));
        mConnectMenuItem.setEnabled(!(isConnecting || isConnected));

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Respond to menu item selections
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.reconnect_reader_menu_item:
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "重新连接中...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            reconnectDevice();
            UpdateUI();
            return true;

        case R.id.insecure_connect_reader_menu_item:
            // Choose a device and connect to it
            selectDevice();
            return true;

        case R.id.disconnect_reader_menu_item:
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "断开连接中...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            disconnectDevice();
            displayReaderState();
            return true;

        case R.id.reset_reader_menu_item:
            resetReader();
            UpdateUI();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    //
    private void UpdateUI() {
        //boolean isConnected = getCommander().isConnected();
        //TODO: configure UI control state
    }


    private void scrollResultsListViewToBottom() {
        mResultsListView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
                mResultsListView.setSelection(mResultsArrayAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void scrollBarcodeListViewToBottom() {
        mBarcodeResultsListView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
                mBarcodeResultsListView.setSelection(mBarcodeResultsArrayAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // AsciiCommander message handling
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //
    // Handle the messages broadcast from the AsciiCommander
    //
    private BroadcastReceiver mCommanderMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (D) { Log.d(getClass().getName(), "AsciiCommander state changed - isConnected: " + getCommander().isConnected()); }

            String connectionStateMsg = intent.getStringExtra(AsciiCommander.REASON_KEY);
            Toast.makeText(context, connectionStateMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            displayReaderState();
            if( getCommander().isConnected() )
            {
                // Update for any change in power limits
                setPowerBarLimits();
                // This may have changed the current power level setting if the new range is smaller than the old range
                // so update the model's inventory command for the new power value
                mModel.getCommand().setOutputPower(mPowerLevel);

                mModel.resetDevice();
                mModel.updateConfiguration();
            }

            UpdateUI();
        }
    };

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Reader reset
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //
    // Handle reset controls
    //
    private void resetReader() {
        try {
            // Reset the reader
            FactoryDefaultsCommand fdCommand = FactoryDefaultsCommand.synchronousCommand();
            getCommander().executeCommand(fdCommand);
            String msg = "Reset " + (fdCommand.isSuccessful() ? "succeeded" : "failed");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            UpdateUI();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Power seek bar
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //
    // Set the seek bar to cover the range of the currently connected device
    // The power level is set to the new maximum power
    //
    private void setPowerBarLimits()
    {
        DeviceProperties deviceProperties = getCommander().getDeviceProperties();

        mPowerSeekBar.setMax(deviceProperties.getMaximumCarrierPower() - deviceProperties.getMinimumCarrierPower());
        mPowerLevel = deviceProperties.getMaximumCarrierPower();
        mPowerSeekBar.setProgress(mPowerLevel - deviceProperties.getMinimumCarrierPower());
    }


    //
    // Handle events from the power level seek bar. Update the mPowerLevel member variable for use in other actions
    //
    private OnSeekBarChangeListener mPowerSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // Nothing to do here
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            // Update the reader's setting only after the user has finished changing the value
            updatePowerSetting(getCommander().getDeviceProperties().getMinimumCarrierPower() + seekBar.getProgress());
            mModel.getCommand().setOutputPower(mPowerLevel);
            mModel.updateConfiguration();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            updatePowerSetting(getCommander().getDeviceProperties().getMinimumCarrierPower() + progress);
        }
    };

    private void updatePowerSetting(int level)  {
        mPowerLevel = level;
        mPowerLevelTextView.setText( mPowerLevel + " dBm");
    }


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Button event handlers
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Scan action
    private OnClickListener mScanButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                mResultTextView.setText("");
                // Perform a transponder scan
                IMakeHttpCall();
                UpdateUI();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    // Clear action
    private OnClickListener mClearButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                // Clear the list
                mResultsArrayAdapter.clear();
                mBarcodeResultsArrayAdapter.clear();

                UpdateUI();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Handler for changes in session
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mActionSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if( mModel.getCommand() != null ) {
                QuerySession targetSession = (QuerySession)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                mModel.getCommand().setQuerySession(targetSession);
                mModel.updateConfiguration();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    };


    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Handler for changes in FastId
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private OnClickListener mFastIdCheckBoxListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                CheckBox fastIdCheckBox = (CheckBox)v;
                mModel.getCommand().setUsefastId(fastIdCheckBox.isChecked() ? TriState.YES : TriState.NO);
                mModel.updateConfiguration();

                UpdateUI();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    public void IMakeHttpCall(){
        String url = "http://192.168.1.76:4300/lottem/query/toolsstockInventory/";
        Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
        builder.appendQueryParameter("barCode", "1121212121");
        JsonArrayRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(builder.toString(),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject person;
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                person =  response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = person.getString(("toolsName"));
                                mResultTextView.setText(name);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
                // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user credentials.
                // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on client side when sending api request.
                // In this case you can check how client is forming the api and debug accordingly.
                // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle accordingly.
                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                }

            }
        });

        //Set a retry policy in case of SocketTimeout & ConnectionTimeout Exceptions. Volley does retry for you if you have specified the policy.
        mVolleyQueue.add(jsonObjRequest);
    }



}
```

**InventoryModel**

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) 2013 Technology Solutions UK Ltd. All rights reserved.
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.uk.tsl.rfid.samples.inventory;

import android.util.Log;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.ModelBase;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.commands.BarcodeCommand;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.commands.FactoryDefaultsCommand;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.commands.InventoryCommand;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.enumerations.TriState;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.responders.IBarcodeReceivedDelegate;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.responders.ICommandResponseLifecycleDelegate;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.responders.ITransponderReceivedDelegate;
import com.uk.tsl.rfid.asciiprotocol.responders.TransponderData;
import com.uk.tsl.utils.HexEncoding;

import java.util.Locale;


public class InventoryModel extends ModelBase
{

    // Control 
    private boolean mAnyTagSeen;
    private boolean mEnabled;
    public boolean enabled() { return mEnabled; }
    private InventoryActivity IAcitivity;
    public void setEnabled(boolean state)
    {
        boolean oldState = mEnabled;
        mEnabled = state;

        // Update the commander for state changes
        if(oldState != state) {
            if( mEnabled ) {
                // Listen for transponders
                getCommander().addResponder(mInventoryResponder);
                // Listen for barcodes
                getCommander().addResponder(mBarcodeResponder);
            } else {
                // Stop listening for transponders
                getCommander().removeResponder(mInventoryResponder);
                // Stop listening for barcodes
                getCommander().removeResponder(mBarcodeResponder);
            }

        }
    }

    // The command to use as a responder to capture incoming inventory responses
    private InventoryCommand mInventoryResponder;
    // The command used to issue commands
    private InventoryCommand mInventoryCommand;

    // The command to use as a responder to capture incoming barcode responses
    private BarcodeCommand mBarcodeResponder;

    // The inventory command configuration
    public InventoryCommand getCommand() { return mInventoryCommand; }

    public InventoryModel()
    {

        // This is the command that will be used to perform configuration changes and inventories
        mInventoryCommand = new InventoryCommand();
        mInventoryCommand.setResetParameters(TriState.YES);
        // Configure the type of inventory
        mInventoryCommand.setIncludeTransponderRssi(TriState.YES);
        mInventoryCommand.setIncludeChecksum(TriState.YES);
        mInventoryCommand.setIncludePC(TriState.YES);
        mInventoryCommand.setIncludeDateTime(TriState.YES);

        // Use an InventoryCommand as a responder to capture all incoming inventory responses
        mInventoryResponder = new InventoryCommand();

        // Also capture the responses that were not from App commands 
        mInventoryResponder.setCaptureNonLibraryResponses(true);

        // Notify when each transponder is seen
        mInventoryResponder.setTransponderReceivedDelegate(new ITransponderReceivedDelegate() {

            int mTagsSeen = 0;
            @Override
            public void transponderReceived(final TransponderData transponder, boolean moreAvailable) {
                mAnyTagSeen = true;
                final String tidMessage = transponder.getTidData() == null ? "" : HexEncoding.bytesToString(transponder.getTidData());
                final String infoMsg = String.format(Locale.US, "\nRSSI: %d  PC: %04X  CRC: %04X", transponder.getRssi(), transponder.getPc(), transponder.getCrc());
                IAcitivity.IMakeHttpCall();
                sendMessageNotification("条形码:"+transponder.getEpc());
                mTagsSeen++;
                if( !moreAvailable) {
                    sendMessageNotification("");
                    Log.d("扫描次数",String.format("扫描到的次数: %s", mTagsSeen));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting complete code just post relevant codes and error logcat.

Comment: So, I didn't find where the _IAcitivity_ is initialized

Comment: where is the exception stacktrace?